# ignore last typed if not alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, meteor

This code needs to ignore the last key pressed if not an alphanumeric, but since I don't know how, I decided it to delete the last typed key if not alphanumeric, The condition evaluates fine but the event line is not doing what's expected.
How can it be done? Thanks

```js
Template.content.events({
  'keyup input': function (event, template) {
    if (!(event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 90)) {  //not alphanumeric
      event.trigger(jQuery.Event("keydown", {keyCode: 20}));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think `event` has any method called `trigger` (or does it?)

Comment: @apokryfos - it does **not**, the OP probably wanted `$(event.target)`, or just `$(this)`

Comment: What do you mean by "last key pressed", those events fire on every inputted value, so you could probably just do `this.value = this.value,replace(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i, '')` instead

Comment: And keyCode `20` would be hitting the caps-lock button, why would you want to trigger that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `event.preventDefault()` on the keydown event to ignore all keydown or keypress events that are not alphanumeric. Something like

```
'keydown input': function (event, template) {
  if (...) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```